# 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' in Dask

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, dask, dask-distributed

I have a function `para_func` that takes a dataframe as input and returns a dataframe. I would like to group rows in `df` and apply function `para_func`. Finally, I have an error

```
distributed.worker - WARNING -  Compute Failed
Function:  execute_task
args:      ((subgraph_callable, 'root', None, <function para_func at 0x000002F044CAC1F0>, 'drop_by_shallow_copy-b7fa028b7c197981e52eea9f870f36c8', (<function _concat at 0x000002F030567430>, [            id parent_id     root  _partitions
0      cqug90j   cqug2sr  cqug2sr            0
1      cqug90k    34fvry   34fvry            0
2      cqug90z   cqu80zb  cqu80zb            0
3      cqug91c   cqtdj4m  cqtdj4m            0
4      cqug91e   cquc4rc  cquc4rc            0
...        ...       ...      ...          ...
99995  cqv8wz8   cqv1gg9   34hylq            0
99996  cqv8wzj    34i1r5   34i1r5            0
99997  cqv8wzv    34jasa   34jasa            0
99998  cqv8wzx   cqv8k2k   34jasa            0
99999  cqv8x08   cquywos   34hywb            0

[100000 rows x 4 columns]], False), ['_partitions'], 'simple-shuffle-ead8404542740024e1572ac449733a42'))
kwargs:    {}
Exception: AttributeError("'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'")
```

Could you please elaborate on how to solve the error?

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd
client = Client(n_workers=4, threads_per_worker=2, processes=False, memory_limit='20GB')

def para_func(tmp_df):

    siblings = pd.DataFrame({'id': tmp_df['id'], 'num_siblings': tmp_df.groupby('parent_id')['parent_id'].transform('count') - 1})

    children = tmp_df.groupby(by = 'id').size().reindex(tmp_df['id'], fill_value = 0).to_frame().reset_index(level = 0).rename(columns = {0: 'num_children'})

    att_df = siblings.merge(children, how = 'left', on = 'id')
    
    return att_df

path = r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/sample_df2.csv'
df = dd.read_csv(path, header = 0)

result = df.groupby('root').apply(para_func, meta = object)
computed_result = result.compute()
```

Comment: What is the return type of `para_func`?

Comment: @mdurant It returns a dataframe.

Comment: hello Akira, by any chance have you resolved your problem? i have the similar problem too

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass DataFrame object that describes the output of para_func function as meta parameter of apply function. It should be the empty DataFrame with the same structure (column names and types of the columns) as the DataFrame returned by para_func function.

Comment: Can you pls share code with the required changes so that it is clear on what you are suggesting

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31768552)